# Coping a row from sheet to another based on whether the candidate is accepted or rejected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Now, I'm trying to create a semi automated tool in google sheets for hiring (self-use). I need a code to copy the whole row based on whether the candidate is (Accepted or Rejected) if the candidate is accepted I want to copy the whole row and paste it in the (Accepted Candidates Sheet).

Can anyone support me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome. Can I clarify this, please correct me if I'm wrong. You are collecting information from candidates (source/format/timing not explained). A candidate can be "Accepted" (not explained how this is identified/triggered). If a candidate is "Accepted" you want to copy the row of information about that candidate and copy (append?) it to a separate sheet of "Accepted Candidates". There would be quite a few precedents for this; would you summarise the research that have you done. Lastly, are you familiar with writing apps script, and would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: No, I'm not a familiar with apps script. I will choose whether he's accepted or rejected, then, if he's accepted i want the whole row (personal information to be copied in another sheet it's called (Accepted Candidates).

Answer (score 1):

You want to update details of "Accepted" candidates to a second, dedicated sheet.

A few questions stand out:

**Q1** - How does one know whether a candidate has been "accepted"?
A - The Column "Accepted?" includes the word "Accepted"

**Q2** - How do you make sure that a candidate is not continually added to the Accepted list?
A - Create an "Updated" Column, manually insert a checkbox. If the box is unticked, then the candidate has not been updated; if the box IS ticked, then the Candidate has already been updated and won't be included in any further updates.

**Q3** - How will the update process be triggered?
A - Introduce a Custom Menu with a menu option "Update acceptances" linked to the update script.

---

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Update acceptances', 's5921910703')
      .addToUi();
}

function s5921910703() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var candidates=ss.getSheetByName('Candidates');
  var acceptances=ss.getSheetByName('Acceptances');

  // zero-based column numbers for Candidates sheet
  var acceptedCol = 2;  
  var candidatesLR = candidates.getLastRow();
  var candidatesRange=candidates.getRange(1,1,candidatesLR,3);
  var candidatesValues=candidatesRange.getValues();

  // get the updated? column
  var updateRange = candidates.getRange(1,4,candidatesLR);
  var updateValues = updateRange.getValues();

  // create a temporary data array 
  var approvedarray = [];

  // loop through the rows on Candidates  
  for (var i= 0;i<candidatesValues.length;i++){

    // test for approval and existing update
    if (candidatesValues[i][acceptedCol] ==='Accepted' && updateValues[i] == 'false'){
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i = "+i+" is 'accepted'");

      // create temporary line array
      var approvedline = [];
      approvedline.push(candidatesValues[i][0]);
      approvedline.push(candidatesValues[i][1]);
      approvedarray.push(approvedline);
      // change updated to true 
      updateValues[i]= ['true'];
    }
    else
    {
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i = "+i+" is NOT 'accepted'");
    }

  }

  // test for any updates
  if (approvedarray.length!=0){
    acceptances.getRange(acceptances.getLastRow()+1,1,approvedarray.length,2).setValues(approvedarray)
    updateRange.setValues(updateValues);
  }

}
```

---

**Candidates - BEFORE**

### [image: Candidates - BEFORE]

**Candidates - AFTER**

### [image: Candidates - AFTER]

**Acceptances after update**

[image: Acceptances after update]

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyIf() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fromsh=ss.getSheetByName('this sheet');
  var tosh=ss.getSheetByName('Accepted Candidates Sheet')
  var rg=fromsh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var hA=vA[0];
  vA.splice(0,1);
  var hObj={};//header columns
  var aObj={};//header indices
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){hObj[h]=i+1;aObj[h]=i;});
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[aObj['Decision Column Title']]=='Accepted') {
      tosh.appendRow(vA[i]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: there is an error in  tosh.appendRow(vA[i]); and I don't even what does it mean.

Comment: What is the error? Did you update the sheet names and the Decision Column Title.  Is the header row 1?  Please share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, I did update. the problem is every time will copy the whole accepted candidates in the other sheet. I need to remove the duplication from the accepted candidate sheet. I found the below code but it doesn't work function If Not IsError(Application.Match(Val(Me.txtPersNum.Text), Sheets("Accepted Candidates").Columns(1), 0)) Then
MsgBox "duplicate"
Else
'update it
End If
}
}